# SQL Inserting multiples values using the result of a select

Tags: sql

How can I use the value of a select to insert multiple values? I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    (id, value1, value2)
VALUES
    (id1, 1, 1),
    (id1, 3, 1),
    (id1, 4, 1),
    ...
    (id2, 1, 1),
    (id2, 3, 1),
    (id1, 4, 1),
    ...
```

But I want to get id1, id2, etc from a select:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table2
WHERE name like '%bla%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ids AS TABLE(id int not null primary key identity(1,1), targetId int)

INSERT INTO @ids (targetId)
    SELECT ID
    FROM Table2
    WHERE name like '%bla%'

DECLARE @i AS int
DECLARE @n AS int
DECLARE @id AS int

SET @n = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @ids)
SET @i = 1

WHILE ( @i <= @n )
BEGIN
    SELECT @id = targetId FROM @ids WHERE id = @i

    INSERT INTO Table1
        (ID, Value1, Value2)
    VALUES
        (@id, 1, 1),
        (@id, 4, 1),
        (@id, 5, 1)

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(id, value1, value2)
SELECT ID,value1, value2
FROM Table2
WHERE value1 like '%bla%'
```

Comment: But value1, value2 are not from Table2, I need to insert them manually.

Comment: Are you selecting them from another table first, then inserting them, or just typing them into your query?  What you appeared to ask first was answered above, with the nested query.

Comment: Just typing. There is no value1, value2 in Table2, they are new values that I need to insert manually. Only the ids are stored in Table2.